# Django application, vue.js only works if the the vue is in the HTML file

Tags: django, vue.js

I have a django application, and im using vue.js, however the vue.js only works if the the vue is in the HTML file. As soon as I move it into a separate JS file it no longer work.I'm wondering if i'm missing something super obvious
HTML FILE

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/JS/main.js'%}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div class="con">

      <button type="button" name="button" @click='addForm()'>
          new
      </button>

      <div class="car-body" v-for="(post, index) in posts">
        <span style="float:right;background-color:green"
          @click='removeForm(index)'>
          x
        </span>
        <h4>Add Article (index:{{ index }})</h4>
        <div >
          <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Title"
            v-models='post.title'>
          <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Preview"
            v-models='post.preview'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endblock content %}
```

JS file

```
var app= new Vue({
  el: '.con',
  data:{
    posts: [
    {
      title:'',
      preview:''
    }
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    addForm(){
      this.posts.push({
        title: '',
        preview:''
      })
    },
    removeForm(){
      this.posts.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: `it no longer work` - any error message? Please ensure that this is not a "static files configuration" problem, check browser console output for any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts should be at the end of `body`.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HBL</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="application">
         <greeting></greeting>
      </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="esterno.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Isn't ```$( document ).ready(function()``` a jquery code? Seeing as he's not importing jquery library, might be good to consider an alternative to that using vanilla js

Comment: I'd recommend loading the Vue.js file as @Azy_Crw4282 described in their HTML part. I would *not* load the script files via jquery as this is against the whole Vue.js idea imho.

Also, make use of the Django {% static %} prefix as in

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'esterno.js' %}"></script>

Comment: Thanks for your comments. With some research, I seem to have understood why the use of jquery is not a good idea-edited the post to reflect it.